# Make birthday picker field required in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the [birthday plugin](https://grantm.github.io/jquery-datetextentry/) and wrote the code below, but even when I leave this section without entering birthday it allows me to continue.

How can I make this field required?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>birthday picker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetextentry.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetextentry.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Date of birth</label>
<input id="date7" type="text" name="date7" required >
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#date7').datetextentry({
    min_year         : '2000',
    max_date         : function() { return this.get_today(); },
    max_date_message : 'Date must not be in the future'
});
```

Comment: Pls show whole html.

Comment: Try `$("date7").prop('required',true);` in your javascript file in `$(document).ready(function(){$("date7").prop('required',true);})`

Comment: @Bruno BG It's not working. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. Could you pls show me the whole js. I mean how you put that code into given js?

Answer (score 1):

You Have To Use Jquery Validation on button click event :

**Checkout The Snippest : This Might Be Helpful**

```js
$(function(){
    $('#date7').datetextentry({
    min_year         : '2000',
    max_date         : function() { return this.get_today(); },
    max_date_message : 'Date must not be in the future'
});
$("#btn").click(function(){
 if($("#date7").val() != ""){
    alert("Success Validate");
} else{
alert("Empty");
}
});

});
```

```html
<link href="https://grantm.github.io/jquery-datetextentry/jquery.datetextentry.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://grantm.github.io/jquery-datetextentry/jquery.datetextentry.js"></script>

<label>Date of birth</label>
<input id="date7" type="text" name="date7" required="required" >
<input type="submit" id="btn" />
```

Comment: It's not actually i want. I need ordinary requied red border like when you do the following code: <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Wick" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Full name ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" type="text">

Answer (score -2):

Use a if statment -- if the date is less than todays date then continue else do nothing return false --

```
If(theuserpickeddate <= todaysdate){

  Continue 

}else{

  Alert("date can't be in the future ")

  Do nothing 

  Return false;

}
```

Comment: This answer is not even close to compiling.